# How to describe AWS security group rules using boto python sdk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, boto

I am using AWS cross-account access role on ec2 for getting all security group rules & I have used below code.

```
import boto.ec2
import os
from boto.sts import STSConnection
sts_connection = STSConnection()
assumed_role_object = sts_connection.assume_role(
    role_arn="AWS_ARN",
    role_session_name="AssumeRoleSession"
)

os.environ["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"] =assumed_role_object.credentials.access_key
os.environ["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"] = assumed_role_object.credentials.secret_key
os.environ["AWS_SESSION_TOKEN"] = assumed_role_object.credentials.session_token

conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region("eu-west-1")
groups = conn.get_all_security_groups()
for group in groups:
     print group.name
     for rule in group.rules:
         print rule.ip_protocol, rule.from_port, rule.to_port, rule.grants
```

it is working as expected on base account using role but getting below error when i am trying to use another account(generating temp credentials from ARN using STS). Same credentials are working fine from aws cli when i am trying to execute any command manually or shell script. I can get the security group details using aws cli so there is no issue with authentication.

```
boto.exception.EC2ResponseError: EC2ResponseError: 401 Unauthorized
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response><Errors><Error><Code>AuthFailure</Code><Message>AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials</Message></Error></Errors><RequestID>5e15dcba-9c92-4161-ad7d-3ffdf202c972</RequestID></Response>
```

**Note: I don't want to use AWS Trusted Advisor**

Comment: Are you calling STS from your code? If so, please edit your question and show the code. If not, how are you passing the temporary credentials to your Python code?

Comment: Are you using boto or boto3? You should ideally use the latter.

Comment: As you can see in the code that I am using boto instead of boto3.